# Given a numeric vector how can i efficiently obtain a vector with values that are between the original vectors values?

Tags: r, processing-efficiency

In my masters program I am trying to implement a decission tree. Therefore I at some point have a vector of sorted and unique values of all variable. e.g.

```
sorted_unique <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
```

now in the next step I am looking for all splitting points - I want to obtain the mean value between all values in the original vector.

```
splits <- double(length(sorted_unique) - 1)

for (i in 1:length(splits)) {
  splits[i] <- mean(sorted_unique[i:(i+1)])
}
```

this indeed yields the desired

```
> splits
[1] 2 4 6
```

however since I have to use this procedure a lot of times, it is very interesting to me, if there is a more efficient way to implement this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
sapply(seq_along(sorted_unique), function(x) mean(sorted_unique[c(x, x + 1)]))[-length(sorted_unique)]

[1] 2 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account this question:

how can i efficiently obtain a vector with values that are between the original vectors values?

And taking into account that you have (as a starting point) sorted vector of unique values, you can try this:

```
sorted_unique <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
all_values <- sorted_unique[[1]]:sorted_unique[[length(sorted_unique)]]
between <- all_values[!all_values %in% sorted_unique]
```

Comment: This does not yield the desired result. I would like to get only one split point. If I input `sorted_unique <- seq(1,13,by = 4)` as an example i would get too many values in return. Also I am looking for an approach that works on double vectors also.